# Session Merge - INSERT INTO fail

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am dealing with a reasonable amount of data (~300MB, 0.5mn rows)
I can't have a `add_all` because there's quite a lot of garbage in the data and if and `INSERT INTO` statement fails the whole `add_all` will fail.

I have the following:

```
for acc in accs:
    try:
        with session.begin_nested():
            session.merge(acc)
    except:
        print "skipped id = " + acc.id
session.commit()
```

The above seems running exponentially slower than the `add_all`.
What are the alternatives, with SQL Alchemy, to skip errors and continue inserting the remaining records? `bulk_save_objects` seems not to provide an "ignore error" option.